# How to read 1.5GB .csv file into R in a more efficient and rapid way?

Tags: r

I have big `.csv` data file. I'm trying to read it into **R** by `read.csv()`, but it is taking too much time to read it. Is there any more efficient method to read it?

Comment: `data.table::fread`.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327851/read-csv-is-extremely-slow-in-reading-csv-files-with-large-numbers-of-columns ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Comment: (note that just about any answer that applies to `read.table()` will also be relevant to `read.csv()`)

Comment: ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295819/how-can-i-read-a-csv-more-quickly-in-r?rq=1 ...

Comment: [some benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r)